# Why is the "find" command have options after path while others don't

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, command-line-arguments

```
find / -iname 'foo'
```

Most command line programs have the filename as the last arguments. Pretty much everything with a - or -- in front will be before anything not with a '-' in front. Is this standardized somewhere? Why is find different? Do you know any other programs that have expressions last?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are not options, those are what find calls an "expression".
There are options, too, and they go, in fact, in front of the path.

Checkout out the man page:

```
NAME
     find -- walk a file hierarchy

SYNOPSIS
     find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
     find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
```

Comment: What's the difference between a option and an expression? or why are expressions not options?

Comment: The expressions are evaluated as the files are being traversed. The options impact execution of the program as a whole and take effect before traversal even begins. However, I'll be the last one to say that the find API is particularily pretty or easy to use/understand. They even acknowledge this in the bugs section of the manpage.